# Rails - Testing User Model with Rspec and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I am trying to Test the User Model Spec for User Creation

**factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name {Faker::Name.first_name}
    last_name {Faker::Name.last_name}
    email {Faker::Internet.email}
    username {Faker::Internet.user_name}
    password {Faker::Internet.password}
  end

end
```

**specs/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User, :type => :model do

  context "valid Factory" do
    it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(build(:user)).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context "validations" do
    before { create(:user) }

    context "presence" do
      it { should validate_presence_of :first_name }
      it { should validate_presence_of :last_name }
      it { should validate_presence_of :email }
      it { should validate_presence_of :encrypted_password }
    end

    context "uniqueness" do
      it { should validate_uniqueness_of :email }
      it { should validate_uniqueness_of :username }
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Devise for the USer creation. But i am ending up with the following **Test Failure**

```
User
  valid Factory
    has a valid factory
  validations
    presence
      should require first_name to be set
      should require last_name to be set
      should require email to be set
      should require encrypted_password to be set (FAILED - 1)
    uniqueness
      should require case sensitive unique value for email
      should require case sensitive unique value for username

Failures:

  1) User validations presence should require encrypted_password to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :encrypted_password }
       Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when encrypted_password is set to nil,
       got no errors
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.98827 seconds (files took 6.61 seconds to load)
7 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18 # User validations presence should require encrypted_password to be set
```

Am assuming that the `encrypted_password` will be auto generated by Devise on trying to create the user.

Comment: I guess you should just check the presence of `password` or try giving encrypted_password for users factory like `encrypted_password { Faker::Internet.encrypted_password }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devise does not actually validate the encrypted password since it is created dynamically after validation if the password is "dirty" (changed).

You don't actually need to test the encrypted password in that way since it is an implementation detail. You can test that Database authenticable is working properly by doing something like:

```
it 'is database authenticable' do
  user = User.create(
     email: 'test@example.com', 
    password: 'password123',
    password_confirmation: 'password123'
  )
  expect(user.valid_password?('password123')).to be_truthy
end
```

But the actual value of the test is pretty low. Instead with Devise you you may want to focus on some [end-to-end tests (feature specs)](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara) where you test the user path of signing up and then logging in.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you only test those validations you added, you do not need to test validations added by devise since they are already been tested.

Comment: Not true. If you expect that user is :confirmable, then you should test that it's configured right. Because someone would remove that, and you would never know that it is broken.

Comment: But you are right, you don't need to test logic, only configuration.